# How can I draw more than one pbc boxes on VMD?

Tags: draw, vmd

Right now, I have:
pbc box -color black -width 1
pbc set {4.541 4.541 6.463 69.5 69.5 90}

How can I make another?

Answer (score 1):

[pbc box_draw](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/plugins/pbctools/) allows this. Example:

```
# draw small box
pbc set {10 10 10}
set box0 [pbc box_draw -width 1 -color black]

# draw large box
pbc set {15 15 15}
set box1 [pbc box_draw -width 1 -color black]
```

If you need to delete a box later, you can do it like this:

```
# delete all objects associated with the box
foreach i $box0 {
    graphics top delete $i
}
```